Force-simulation for graph layout: How to avoid particle collapsing into a single point?
In a force-based graph-layout simulation using Barnes-Hut, what are the conditions for collapse? With collapse I mean multiple (or even all) nodes "collapsing" into a single point.
Is there some research I could look into? Any hint is appreciated.
Background: We've written a force simulation to compute a graph-layout. But when running the simulation a bit too long all nodes of the graph collapse into a (or a few) single point(s).
Here You can see a grid of 16 successful simulation runs, and afterwards a collapse, where we chose the parameters a little bit differently.

Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

This might be on-topic at Computational Science Stack Exchange.

You haven’t said anything about the force that you’re simulating. For a reader to understand this, they should not have to read any code, since code is what’s off-topic.

You have presumably implemented some always-repulsive force to keep the vertices apart. If they are instead collapsing, then either you have a bug in the force law or you have a bug in the way that you are moving the vertices under the influence of the force.

Can you repro the problem with just a few vertices? If so, that should make it much easier to debug.

@Ghoster The existence of code doesn't make a question off-topic (not that there's any code here). Inquiring about algorithms to replicate known physics (which is what OP is doing) makes this on-topic here.

@KyleKanos not that there's any code here The OP provided Python code and its output. I don’t see any physics in this question, and the code provided wasn’t useful because it didn’t do any calculation. What is on-topic here about graph layout?

I'm curious about the physics simulation, the graph-layout is a side effect from my point of view. I intentionally didn't point you to the code of the simulation, since I'm curious about general research in this realm.
So I'm not asking about some code: I would like to understand how for example molecule physics simulations deal with issues where repulsion and attraction must be simulated at the same time.
I'm sorry for being so vague. If I had the answer to my question, I could formulate a very precise question..
